# Variable (for asp.net connection string) does not exist in the current context and I can't see why

Tags: asp.net, database, ado.net, database-connection, connection-string

I have tried replicating (almost step by step) the code in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBCPc44CE74&index=3&list=PL6n9fhu94yhX5dzHunAI2t4kE0kOuv4D7 but my 'con' variable causes an error in two places. My code is:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CSDB"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS)) ;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  * FROM  admin_UserRole WHERE Archived = 0", con);
            con.Open();
            RoleGrid.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            RoleGrid.DataBind();

    }

}
```

}

The error occurs for 'con' after my SQL statement and for 'con.Open();' as well.

I'm obviously new to this, so apologies if I'm not making something clear enough to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using statement is closed prematurely... That means... Your `SqlConnection` object gets created and disposed immediately.

So modify your code as following

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CSDB"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS)){

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  * FROM  admin_UserRole WHERE Archived = 0", con);
            con.Open();
            RoleGrid.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            RoleGrid.DataBind();

    }

}
```

Comment: Success! I've finally printed the results to the grid (I had some other compilation error which I caused by messing with the web.config =/)! Thanks a lot!

I didn't need to try the second answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS)) 
{
   if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
   {
     con.Open();
   }

   .......
 }
```